# Is there a way to set the initial browser location using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

We are developing a web page automation program. I'd like to control where the webpage runs. This code moves the browser to a location after a certain amount of time. I want to move my browser right away from the program. How do you have?
The driver uses a chrome driver.

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(200,0));
```

Comment: _...after a certain amount of time..._ exactly when?

Comment: Try this: ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.moveTo(0,0);window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);");

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1750

Comment: The webpage's location is moved when the web driver runs and you connect to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the position of the browser window right after initializing the driver.
Your code would then look like:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(); //or whatever implementation you use
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(200, 0));
```

It is possible to move the browser to another monitor. For example you have two monitors with a resolution of 1920x1080 then you need to set the X-axis to >= 1920.
Then you can maximize the window:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

**Note:** On a Windows system the X-axis depends on your main monitor (Right click on Desktop -> Display settings -> select one monitor and see which one has the checkbox **"Make this my main display"** ticked.

An example:
You have a three monitor setup and your main monitor is in the center. To move your browser to the right screen you need `Point(1920, 0)` and to move it to the left screen you need `Point(-1920, 0)`.

On MacOS this does not work because the main monitor is always the last selected one (mouse click).

Comment: Your answer was very helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to use a chrome driver?

Comment: Yes, just replace RemoteWebDriver with ChromeDriver.